# Ubuntu stops and says failed to start user manager for uid 120

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, amdgpu

I have dual boot on my machine (Windows 10 and Ubuntu) and it has been working fine until I installed a driver for my AMD Radeon GPU. Once I restarted the machine these messages showed up and it just got stuck here.

[image: this image]

What is the solution for this?

NOTE: I have looked for answers and solutions before asking this question and found none.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *radeon* | grep ii` and `dpkg -l *amd* | grep ii`. What version Ubuntu? Where did you get the Radeon driver from? What was the filename?

Comment: @heynnema I cannot access the os to type these commands. I got the file from https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-30

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Can you boot to Recovery Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Boot into Recovery Mode...**

- enter the GRUB menu
- choose "Advanced Options"
- choose the newest kernel ending with "(recovery mode)"
- choose "Root Access"
- enter the root password if required
- enter `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`

**Based on whether you installed the All-Open or Pro components, run one of the following commands:**

Use this for All-Open components...

$ `amdgpu-uninstall`

Use this for Pro components...

$ `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`

Then:

$ `reboot`

*source: http://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/*

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did solve the problem.but do you know how to install the GPU driver the proper way?

Comment: @MahmoudYoussef What version Ubuntu? Did you install the All-Open install, or the Pro install?

Comment: ubuntu 18, and I've installed the pro install

Comment: Since you now know how to uninstall it, you might try the All-Open version and see what happens. Otherwise, contact AMD Support.